# define default parameter value from variable

Tags: jenkins

While defining a build parameter, is it possible to specify an environment variable as a default value? As in the example, I've tried `${BUILD_URL}`, `$BUILD_URL` and other combinations but in the "Build with parameters" screen, it displays the default value as-is instead of getting substituted by the actual variable value. How can I have the actual value in the Build with parameter UI textbox?
[image]